# how to get webElement ID which was clicked at browser using C#?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, selenium-webdriver, element

first of all, I don't want to use "...driver.FindElement..." or any another way that I must to inform any kind of locator like id/xpath/name.

Is there some way to get the id information of a webElement, just clicking on it using C# or Java?

I would like to do something like Selenium IDE does:

1 -  MANUALLY to open browser(IE/Firefox/Chrome..) and access an URL.

2 - MANUALLY to click on some field/element on the page and save its respective id.

```
    <div **id="ThisIsWhatINeed"**>
```

PS: After to get the id information, I need to handle this information on others methods, so I think that the "step 2" above, should be something like a listener with a function returning a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
private Int32 GetTableRowCount(string tableID)
{
    Int32 count = 0;

    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        HtmlElement tableElem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(tableID);
        if (tableElem != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement rowElem in tableElem.GetElementsByTagName("TR"))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw(new ArgumentException("No TABLE with an ID of " + tableID + " exists."));
        }
    }

    return(count);
}
```

Here you may find some information: [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's the problem.. I'm looking for some way to get the elements without to inform any data. Just clicking on the field at the browser base. I'm gonna redo my question, I guess it's a little confuse. Thanks for the attempt sir